# ASP Chart does not render in Design Mode when put in ASP Table

Tags: asp.net

This is the weirdest bug, the ASP Chart by itself render fine in design mode.  But when I put it inside a ASP table, it suddenly does not render anymore.  It throw an "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of the Object"

```
<asp:Table runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">
            <asp:Chart runat="server" BackColor="LightBlue" Width ="1200" Height="150"  
                BackGradientStyle="HorizontalCenter" >
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="LightBlue" 
                        BackGradientStyle="HorizontalCenter">
                        <AxisY IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                            <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 11pt, style=Bold" />
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

HOWEVER, the following code works just fine by itself:

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" BackColor="LightBlue" Width ="1200" Height="150"  
    BackGradientStyle="HorizontalCenter" >
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="LightBlue" 
            BackGradientStyle="HorizontalCenter">
            <AxisY IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 11pt, style=Bold" />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="False">
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code with table into editor and it renders just fine on .NET 4.0. Maybe try to remove all auto-generated properties from .aspx.designer.cs file and resave aspx file to regenerate its content?
What are you doing in code? I mean when and how are you accessing this chart control inside a table?